# Is it possible to shorten the time between uploading an ipa to iTunesConnect and it becoming available?

Tags: app-store-connect

The last release time to TestFlight was:

- 30 seconds build time.
- 4 minutes uploading a 5mb binary.
- 19 minutes waiting for iTunesConnect to make it available.

Is there something we can do with xcode to help apple along or is it completely out of our hands? Right now we end up with a reverse [pomodoro technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) when we're at the tail end of the work. :)

Answer (score 1):

For TestFlight, there's nothing you can do.  However, after the first upload, and Apple's had a chance to do a cursory review, the availability will go much faster.

For submissions to the App Store, there's only 1 way to make this process go (a little bit) faster and that's to request an expedited review.  You would need to justify the quicker review time to Apple, although the rules are fairly lax.  You can do this several times a year but after a few of them Apple might not grant them.

Here's what Apple indicates are the valid reasons for this request:

> **Expedited App Review**
>
> If you face extenuating circumstances, you can request the review of
>   your app to be expedited. These circumstances include fixing a
>   critical bug in your app on the App Store or releasing your app to
>   coincide with an event you are directly associated with.
>
> **Urgent Bug Fix** 
>   If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in
>   your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review,
>   be sure to include the steps to reproduce the bug on the current
>   version of your app.
>
> **Time-Sensitive Event** 
>   For apps associated with an event, we recommend
>   you plan and schedule the release of your app in iTunes Connect.
>   However, if your app is still in review and the launch of your event
>   is quickly approaching, you can request to have your app review
>   expedited. When submitting your request, it's important to include the
>   event, date of the event, and your app's association with the event.
>
> *Please Note*: Expedited reviews are granted on a limited basis and we
>   cannot guarantee that every request will be expedited. Sign in to
>   request an expedited review.

Comment: I'm not asking about review times that takes upwards of weeks, I'm asking about the iTunesConnect processing time that's ~19 minutes.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from the question.  In that case, the answer is definately 'nothing you can do'.